# How much did revolvers cost in Victorian England?

Tags: weapons, victorian, price

What was the general price range for a decent revolver in Victorian England?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a snip from advertisment section of [The British Boys Paper](https://books.google.com/books?id=syNHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA255&dq=english%20revolver%20cost&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU39qZx6vSAhVrxlQKHftiCegQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=english%20revolver%20cost&f=false), dated 1888

> Splendid six chambered revolver plated recently cost 21s sacrifice
>   for 10s 6d also signet ring will sell for 5s Mexican silver chain 1s
>   9d sword stick 1s 3d 20 stringed Zither harp beautiful tone sell for
>   7s 6d good accordion nickle silver front recently cost 9s 6d take 7s
>   quantity of books &c p for list to W Matthews 2 Abbey churchyard Bath

It show the cost (21s) and will sell for 10s.6d.

There are other adds elsewhere in the volume.